# Are polygons piecewise smooth curves?

Tags: real-analysis

What is a clear sign that a curve is not? They have corners, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The edge of the polygon consists of a bunch of straight lines. Straight lines are smooth. The indication that it is, is that there are a finite set of points (the vertices) such that, if you remove them, there rest is smooth. To produce one that is not try putting infinitely many points where it is not smooth.

Comment: Circles and ovals and line segments are smooth.  Polygons are smooth except at the corners; so they're only "piecewise smooth".  That is, they can be broken into finitely many pieces, each of which is smooth -- for a polygon, each piece is a line segment.

Comment: Something like the Koch snowflake would not be piecewise smooth, basically because it has corners everywhere.